# Define new mathematical notations in Latex

Tags: symbols

[image]I need to define some new notations in Latex. I have attached a figure that mentioned them. Is that possible to define them?

Comment: How are they to be used?

Comment: In fact, I want to have \dagger in a circle, similar to \otimes or \oplus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This first implementation will not work in the scriptstyles.  See below for a more flexible answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\hashop{\mathop{\stackengine{-0.5pt}{\#}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcirc$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\def\dagop{\mathop{\stackengine{-0.5pt}{\dag}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcirc$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$X\hashop Y\dagop Z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If scaling with math style is needed, I preserve that here.  EDITED to introduce `\symbolop{}` to allow the method to be extended to other symbols of the user's choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\def\hashop{\symbolop{\#}}
\def\dagop{\symbolop{\dag}}
\def\ddagop{\symbolop{\ddag}}
\def\ampop{\symbolop{\&}}
\newcommand\symbolop[1]{\ThisStyle{\mathop{\stackengine{%
  -0.5\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\SavedStyle\bigcirc$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$X\hashop Y\dagop Z$

$\scriptstyle X\hashop Y\dagop Z$

$\scriptscriptstyle X\hashop Y\dagop Z$

$X \ddagop Y \ampop Z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question. What are the roles of " {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}" in your answer?

Comment: @DavidMayar It is easiest to look at package doc (http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) page 6, but, in summary `O` is over rather than `U`nder stack; `c`enter horizontal alignment rather than `l`eft or `r`ight; `F`alse for quiet mode, in which the stack is built but not output; `F`alse for "useanchorwidth" option to make the stack only as wide as the "anchor" (argument 2); and `L`ongstack which makes argument #1 a baselineskip, rather than with `S`hortstacks where argument #1 is an inter-argument gap.

Comment: I really thank you. Your answer is very perfect. Good luck

Comment: @DavidMayar Please see revision.  I have generalized it to conveniently handle other symbol operators with `\symbolop{}`.